# How to get the memory used by the openGL texture?

Tags: android, memory-management, opengl-es, android-memory

From my app, how can I get the memory used by the openGL textures and also the memory used by bitmaps?

Comment: OpenGL has it's own texture storage, summarised here, https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES doesn't have any query APIs for memory usage, but I presume you know how much data you uploaded though the API in the first place. If you upload a 1MB of static texture then the memory usage will be ~1MB ...

Comment: Will it not be rounded to the nearest alignment?

Comment: Sure, hence the "~", but for most modern hardware the overhead should be insignificant compared to the data itself.